# Prevent form from resetting its values when other form is submitted in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, forms, submit, form-submit

I have two forms, in html, when I submit one of them, the values of the other are reset to default, how can I prevent this behaviour from happening.

Here's the full code:

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="pt-br">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>challenge</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <section class="container">
            <div class="container__box">
                
                <h1>Title</h1>
                <form id="firstForm">
                    <input type="text"><input type="submit" value="Submit">
                </form>
    
                <form class="firstform">
                    <input type="checkbox" id="form2" class=""><label for="form2">Checkbox of separated form, that I do not want to reset when first form is submit s=is clicked.</label>
                </form>
            </div>
        </section>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

To avoid submitting the form, you should use javascript and add preventDefault.

```
const submit = document.querySelector("#firstForm")

submit.addEventListener("submit", (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
})
```

Comment: Now the form isn't being submitted at all … which doesn't really sold the problem.

Answer (score 0):

When you submit a form, the data in it is bundled up into an HTTP request and sent to the server. The server then responds with a new HTML document which the browser displays.

When it generates the new page, the server won't have the data from the other form, so it can't include as it default values in the new page.

There are several approaches you could take:

**Combine the forms** into a single form, then write server-side code to determine which submit button was used to submit the form so you can act on the right set of data, then use the combined data set of both original forms to generate the default values for the new page.

**Don't send any content in the response** and use a [204 status](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/204) instead. The big drawback here is that there's no information passed to the user to tell them that the form was submitted successfully.

Replace the form submission with **Ajax**. Create an event listener for the form's `submit` event, prevent the default behaviour (of submitting the form) and make an HTTP request using [the fetch api](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) instead. Then use [DOM manipulation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Client-side_web_APIs/Manipulating_documents) to present the result to the user.

**Track all the user input with client-side JS** and store it somewhere persistent (such as [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)). Each time the page loads, check for data there to repopulate the fields with.

Comment: Is it possible to combine the forms into a single form and then make some inputs of the form not get reset when it it submitted? If so, how? Anxious to hear from you.
Thanks.

Comment: As I said: "then use the combined data set of both original forms to generate the default values for the new page."

Answer (score -1):

You can use `fetch` to send data.

```html
<html lang="pt-br">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <title>challenge</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <section class="container">
            <div class="container__box">
                <h1>Title</h1>
                <form id="firstForm">
                    <input name="name" />
                    <button id="submit">submit</button>
                </form>

                <form id="secondForm">
                    <input type="checkbox" />
                    <label>
                        Checkbox of separated form, that I do not want to reset
                        when first form is submit s=is clicked.
                    </label>
                </form>
            </div>
        </section>

        <script>
            const firstForm = document.querySelector('#firstForm')
            const submit = firstForm.querySelector('#submit')

            submit.addEventListener('click', async (e) => {
                e.preventDefault()
                let data = {}
                const form = new FormData(firstForm)
                for (const [key, value] of form) {
                    data[key] = value
                }
                await fetch('YOUR_URL', {
                    method: 'YOUR_METHOD',
                    body: JSON.stringify(data),
                })
            })
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```